# Understanding smoothness of map between two smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

> **Lemma:** Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds and let $F:M\to N$ be any map. If $(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})$ are smooth atlases for M and N, respectively, and if for each $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\psi_{\beta}\circ F \circ\psi^{-1}_\alpha$ is smooth on its domain of definition, then $F$ is smooth.

I am confused about what is meant about smoothness of $f$ in differential topology. I am interpreting as synonym of differentiation.

So if $\psi_{\beta}\circ F \circ\psi^{-1}_\alpha$ is differentiable that means F is differentiable hence smooth.

The domain where $F$ must be differentiable is given by $\psi^{-1}_{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ considering M m-dimensional.

And considering another atlas $(U'_{\alpha},\psi'_{\alpha})$ on M.

$F\circ\psi'^{-1}_{\alpha}=F\circ\psi^{-1}_{\alpha}\circ\psi_{\alpha}\circ\psi'^{-1}_{\alpha}$

Since $F\circ\psi^{-1}_{\alpha}$ is smooth and $\psi_{\alpha}\circ\psi'^{-1}_{\alpha}$ is also smooth then $F\circ\psi'^{-1}_{\alpha}$ is smooth. Since $(U'_{\alpha},\psi'_{\alpha})$ is arbitrary then F is smooth on all M.

Considering another atlas  $(U'_{\beta},\psi'_{\beta})$ on N.

$\psi'_{\beta} F \psi'^{-1}_{\alpha}=\psi'_{\beta}\circ\psi^{-1}_{\beta}\circ\psi_{\beta}\circ F\circ\psi^{-1}_{\alpha}\circ\psi_{\alpha}\circ\psi'^{-1}_{\alpha}$

is also smooth by the same argument, where I think the coordinate transformation in $N$ is superfluous.

**Question:**

Am I proving what the statement asks? Am I understanding smoothness in the context of differential manifolds mapping? I would appreciate if someone could clarify me on this topic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Smoothness is a lot stronger than differentiability. Please give the definition your course (book) is using for $F$ to be smooth.

Comment: @TedShifrin       Thanks for your comment.In my course book that is not defined. I have consulted another book where the defintion is: "$f:M\to\mathbb{R}^k$ is said to be smooth if ,for every smooth char $(U,\phi)$ on M, the composite function $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is smooth on the open set $\phi(U)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$"

Comment: Well, if we don't have a definition, I'm going to say that your "lemma" is the usual definition.

Comment: @TedShifrin In my course book there is no definition(the book chosen by the Professor). However the book where I found this lemma, the definition is the one I wrote in the previous comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, you still don't have a definition for smoothness of a mapping between manifolds.

Comment: @TedShifrin               So as you said the lemma might be a definition. So what do you think of my attempted proof?

Comment: @TedShifrin "Let M and N be smooth manifolds $f:M\to N$ continuous. Then f is smooth at $p\in M$ if there are charts (U,\phi) around p and $(V,\psi)$ around f(p) such that $\psi\circ f \circ\phi^{-1}:\phi(U)\to \psi(U)$ is smooth"

Comment: This is effectively a restatement of the lemma. I think this is pointless to try to do with no definition. Why don't you look at other texts or ask your professor for clarification?

Comment: @TedShifrin             In other books this apparently is a definition but not in the book where I found the lemma(Introduction to smooth manifolds by John M. Lee), whose proof was left as an exercise to the reader.